# Not able to figure out from where width property getting inherited from

Tags: html, css, frontend, tailwind-css

I was trying to style a banner for the picture and wrote the code for the same which I have attached below. I have set the width of the image to around 70% of the parent container and margin-left to auto, but on inspecting the rendered image it is showing width of 100% of the parent container. Am not able to figure out where the width is getting inherited and how can I rectify it.

Below is the CSS tailwind code for the same

```
import React from "react";
import Image from "next/image.js";

const EachBannerSlide = ({ bannerUrl, title }) => {
  return (
    <div className=" carousel-container relative w-full h-full py-5 px-0 overflow-x-hidden  mt-5">
      <div className="carousel flex h-full w-11/12 relative m-auto bg-black">
        <div className="slider bg-black rounded flex-none h-full mr-8 overflow-hidden relative left-0 w-full">
          <img src={bannerUrl} alt={title}  className="block ml-auto min-h-full object-cover w-3/5" loading="lazy" />
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>

  );
};
```

Despite giving w-3/5, the image is appearing on the whole of the banner!!

Any help is highly appreciated!!

**EDIT** :
[image]

This is what I am getting
and on inspecting element it is showing
[image]

Width 100% is getting rendered.

and below is the property of the parent container

[image]

Comment: `w-3/5` is not valid because contains a `/`

Comment: w-3/5 is a valid class name, it's a default class of tailwind so sure its valid

Comment: ok I mean it should be escaped... by the way that's the culprit.. if you changed that identifier it worked with no escaping

Comment: Perhaps in react, but in vue there is no need to escape it

Comment: I was chasing that path because I tried myself defining the css rule with that class name and worked only when removing the slash character. By the way it was possibly a false track because those rules are generated and could be taken for granted. In case I apologize for polluting the thread

Comment: What CSS properties `.slider` has?

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of what you get? Maybe reproduce it in tailwind play?

Comment: @ChenBr I have added the screen shots

Comment: @IharAliakseyenka I haven't given slider any properties. Just for easy identification have given it a className. All the CSS properties are in the tailwind only,

Comment: If you have control over `globals.css` file, you may change CSS there. Or set more specific selector to specific carousel slide. Otherwise, change `w-3/5` to `max-w-[60%]`. And don't forget about media queries on mobile, something like `max-w-full sm:max-w-[60%]`